# CGAL construct sphere polyhedron

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm new to CGAL, and currently need to compute spherical polyhedra area using CGAL. However, I'm stuck at the first step, i.e. constructing sphere polyhedra from sphere points. Here is my code

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_S2<K> Nef_polyhedron;
typedef Nef_polyhedron::Sphere_point Sphere_point;
typedef Nef_polyhedron::Sphere_segment Sphere_segment;
typedef Nef_polyhedron::SVertex_const_iterator SVertex_const_iterator;

Sphere_point p1(1, 0, 0),  p2(0, 0, 1), p3(1, -1, 0);
Sphere_segment s1(p1, p2), s2(p2, p3), s3(p3, p1);
std::vector<Sphere_segment> tri({ s1, s2, s3 });
Nef_polyhedron S(tri.begin(), tri.end());

int i = 0;
for (SVertex_const_iterator it = S.svertices_begin(); it != S.svertices_end(); ++it)
{
    Sphere_point p = it->point();
    std::cout << "Point " << i << ":" << p.x() << " " << p.y() << " " << p.z() << std::endl;
    i += 1;
}
```

I'm expecting the output to be of size three, which correspond to the three sphere triangle vertices. However, I'm getting 6 vertices:

```
Point 0:0 -1 0
Point 1:-1 -0 -0
Point 2:0 0 1
Point 3:1 -1 0
Point 4:1 0 0
Point 5:0 1 0
```

My question is how can I construct a sphere polyhedron enclosed by the input sphere segments, with the polyhedron to the left-hand side of the first input segment?

**update** I attempted to construct the polyhedron from another approach, i.e. by computing the intersection of several hemispheres. This seems to guarantee the number of vertices in the constructed sphere polyhedron matches the input, given the input coordinates are integers. But the code throws an error when the input is a general `double` type number. Here is the code

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Ker;
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_S2<Ker> Nef_polyhedron;
typedef Nef_polyhedron::Sphere_circle Sphere_circle;
typedef Nef_polyhedron::Sphere_point Sphere_point;

//CPoint is my custom Cartesian point class that 
//support vector cross product, which I used to 
//compute the normal. Its Cartesian coordinates 
//can be accessed by [] operator.
Nef_polyhedron bd_vert_to_sph_poly(const std::vector<CPoint>& pts)
{
    size_t n = pts.size();
    //! 1. compute half-spheres using normal
    std::cout << "Input Cartesian Coordinates:" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Sphere_circle> circles(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        CPoint p1 = pts[i];
        CPoint p2 = pts[(i + 1) % n];
        CPoint normal = p1 ^ p2;
        circles[i] = Sphere_circle(normal[0], normal[1], normal[2]);
        std::cout << p1[0] << " " << p1[1] << " " << p1[2] << std::endl;
    }
    //! 2. intersect S
    Nef_polyhedron S = Nef_polyhedron(Nef_polyhedron::COMPLETE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        S *= Nef_polyhedron(circles[i]);
    }
    //debugging
    std::cout << "Consturct vertices Cartesian:" << std::endl;
    for (SVertex_const_iterator it = S.svertices_begin(); it != S.svertices_end(); ++it)
    {
        CPoint p(CGAL::to_double(it->point().x()),
            CGAL::to_double(it->point().y()),
            CGAL::to_double(it->point().z()));
        std::cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << std::endl;
    }
    return S;
}
```

The input `pts` consists of 7 vertices, with `double` type Cartesian coordinates. This code throws me an error at the first call at the line

```
S *= Nef_polyhedron(circles[i]); // i==0 when error occurs
```

Here in the runtime, `normal[0] = -0.0076270755275557253, normal[1] = 0.0062103059131449548, normal[2] = 0.016149138504648830`(digits are truncated. You could recover them by normalizing the normal vector by calling sqrt function). And the shell output is

```
CGAL error: assertion violation!
Expression : c.has_on(p1)&&c.has_on(p2)
File       : C:\dev\CGAL-5.1.1\include\CGAL/Nef_S2/Sphere_segment.h
Line       : 53
Explanation:
Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at https://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html
```

By looking into the calling stack, the error comes from the precondition that examines whether a point is on a sphere. So my question here is how can I make the above code work?

I tried to walk around this problem, by changing the kernel to `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel`, which allows exact computing. Now there is no error thrown, but the computation result is incorrect, which is

```
Input Cartesian Coordinates:
0.733412 0.674178 0.0871214
0.722935 0.686566 0.0774091
0.721097 0.688361 0.0785988
0.710427 0.695728 0.106097
0.726191 0.675485 0.127931
0.739532 0.663825 0.111483
0.739734 0.66373 0.110705

Consturct vertices Cartesian:
1.15104e-274 1.07067e-274 2.02774e-275
0 0 0
0 0 0
1.40006e-136 1.37109e-136 2.09089e-137
6.67726e-235 6.13797e-235 7.93185e-236
5.9606e-63 5.69e-63 6.49699e-64
4.11434e-27 3.90736e-27 4.40548e-28
```

The output sphere vertices coordinates do not match the input ones. I also tried to convert the type of `normal[i]` from `double` to `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel::FT`, but the result remains the same. Is there a way to make these coordinates match, or at least close?

Answer (score 0):

You've got six vertices after creation a spherical polygon with three segments, because you explore not only your polygon, but the whole [DCEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list), representing the sphere partition into *faces*. Each face is bounded by an outer cycle of *halfedges* (in the simplest case), and it can contain holes, bounded also by cycles of halfedges. The code below shows how to explore faces of such partition one by one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <CGAL/Exact_rational.h>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_S2.h>

using Kernel = CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Exact_rational>;
using SPolygon = CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_S2<Kernel>;
using SPoint = SPolygon::Sphere_point;
using SSegment = SPolygon::Sphere_segment;

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

std::string pointAsString(const SPoint& P)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "(" << P.x() << "," << P.y() << "," << P.z() << ")";
  return ss.str();
}

std::string halfEdgeCycleAsString(const SPolygon::SHalfedge_const_iterator HEIT)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  auto heit = HEIT; 
  while (true)
  {
    ss << pointAsString(heit->source()->point()) << " => " << pointAsString(heit->target()->point());
    heit = heit->snext();
    if (heit != HEIT)
    {
      ss << ", ";
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  return ss.str();
}

void printFaces(const SPolygon& P)
{
  unsigned i = 0;
  for (auto fit = P.sfaces_begin(); fit != P.sfaces_end(); ++fit)
  {
    cout << "face #" << i++ << ":" << endl;
    for (auto fcit = fit->sface_cycles_begin(); fcit != fit->sface_cycles_end(); ++fcit)
    {
      cout << "  face boundary:" << endl;
      if (fcit.is_svertex())
      {
        const SPolygon::SVertex_const_handle vit = fcit;
        cout << "    vertex " << pointAsString(vit->point()) << endl;
      }
      else if (fcit.is_shalfedge())
      {
        const SPolygon::SHalfedge_const_handle heit = fcit;
        cout << "    halfedge cycle [" << halfEdgeCycleAsString(heit) << "]" << endl;
      }
      else if (fcit.is_shalfloop())
      {
        const SPolygon::SHalfloop_const_handle hlit = fcit;
        cout << "    halfloop (" << hlit->circle() << ")" << endl;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  const SPoint p1(1, 0, 0),  p2(0, 0, 1), p3(1, -1, 0);
  const std::vector<SSegment> v{{p1, p2}, {p2, p3}, {p3, p1}};
  const SPolygon p(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
  p.print_statistics();
  printFaces(p);
}
```

The output of this program:

```
Sphere Map - Statistics
|V| = 6
|E| = 14
|L| = 0
|F| = 3
|Fcs| = 3

face #0:
  face boundary:
    halfedge cycle [(-1,0,0) => (0,-1,0), (0,-1,0) => (1,-1,0), (1,-1,0) => (0,0,1), (0,0,1) => (1,0,0), (1,0,0) => (0,1,0), (0,1,0) => (-1,0,0)]
face #1:
  face boundary:
    halfedge cycle [(1,0,0) => (0,0,1), (0,0,1) => (1,-1,0), (1,-1,0) => (1,0,0)]
face #2:
  face boundary:
    halfedge cycle [(1,-1,0) => (0,-1,0), (0,-1,0) => (-1,0,0), (-1,0,0) => (0,1,0), (0,1,0) => (1,0,0), (1,0,0) => (1,-1,0)]
```

Another problem in your code - you shouldn't use `double` numbers with `Simple_cartesian` kernel, because this kernel requires rational numbers, supporting exact calculations. Also, if you have non-integer input data, you'll need to convert them into rationals:

```
SPoint p(1, 0, CGAL::Exact_rational(119, 31));
```

If you use `119/31` here instead, this z-coordinate will be rounded to `3`.

---

**UPDATE.** You can traverse only the part of the DCEL, which is important for you - for example, all edges of the polygon you've created. One way to do that is below:

```
int main()
{
  const SPoint p1(1, 0, 0),  p2(0, 0, 1), p3(1, -1, 0);
  const std::vector<SSegment> v{{p1, p2}, {p2, p3}, {p3, p1}};
  const SPolygon p(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
  // ------ locate the starting vertex of this polygon and output its halfedge cycle
  const auto h = p.locate(p1);
  SPolygon::SVertex_const_handle vh = nullptr;
  if (CGAL::assign(vh, h))
  {
    cout << halfEdgeCycleAsString(vh->out_sedge()) << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Vertex is not found" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and it's very informative. I still have two quick questions. 1) Can I construct the sphere polyhedron from just its boundary (perhaps oriented) segments? Because here I don't need a partition of the whole surface. 2) For the kernel of type `Exact_rational`, can I use `to_rational` to convert a double number to rational type?

Comment: @yang - when you create a spherical polygon you create a corresponding DCEL, which defines a partition. So iterators like `SVertex_const_iterator` will iterate through *this* partition. However you can forget about this partition and iterate only through the polygon you just created - use the function `locate` to find a DCEL object, containing the first point of the polygon, convert this object to the vertex handle, and use the `out_sedge` function to find the first halfedge of your polygon

Comment: @yang - as for the `to_rational` function - yes, you can use it. However the `Exact_rational` constructor can convert doubles to rationals - it looks simpler